# How to tell web pack to use external js file url without freezing in in bundle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, chromecast

There is a simple task:
I want to try making a Google Chromecast receiver app (which is SPA). Google Chromecast SDK (cast SDK) [requires](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver/basic) their framework to be on external url. Also this framework creates global `cast` object.

What is the correct way of creating this webpack application?
The targets I want to achieve:

- Build `index.html` with `HtmlWebpackPlugin`
- Develop using import this framework (`import cast from ???`)
- Avoid bundling it (probably using [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals))?
- Ensure `cast` object created by this js file is global (`ProvidePlugin`?)
- Add `<script src="http://cdn....js"></script>` into HTML created by `HtmlWebpackPlugin`

For now I am trying to setup simple app, and I got stuck on last step - adding `<script>` tag to output html, but I'm sure that there are mistakes I've done on prev steps.

Could you help guiding me through this process?

---

My current webpack.config.js is:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.svg$/, use: 'svg-inline-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] },
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      scriptLoading: 'defer',
      hash: true,
      
    }) ,
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      cast: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'src/cast_receiver_framework'))
    }) 
  ],
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',
  devServer: {
    compress: false,
    disableHostCheck: true
 },
 externalsType: 'script',
 externals: {
  cast_receiver_framework: ['//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/caf_receiver/v3/cast_receiver_framework.js', 'cast']
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your last step you can use the `template` param of `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to customize your template.

By default `HtmlWebpackPlugin` will inject bundled modules at the end of the `<body>`.

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options) if you need further customization.

---

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <!-- Whatever else you might need -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="your-mount-point-id"></div>

        <script src="http://cdn....js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**webpack.config.js**

```js
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, "path/to/index.html"),
        scriptLoading: 'defer',
        hash: true,
    })
],
```